# NSFileManager leaks

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa, memory-management, nsfilemanager

I discovered memory leaks in the following snippet of code I wrote

```
NSFileManager *fileManager=[[NSFileManager alloc] init];
fileList=[[fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:DOCUMENTS_FOLDER error:nil] retain];
[fileManager release];
```

Leaks info –

```
[NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:]
[NSFileManager directoryContentsAtPath:matchingExtension:options:keepExtension:error]
CFStringCreateWithBytes
_CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3
_CFRuntimeCreateInstance.
```

And I don't know how to solve it?

Comment: Are you releasing `fileList` later?

Answer (score 4):

Your alloc-then-release of the file manager is fine. But

> `fileList=[[fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:DOCUMENTS_FOLDER error:nil] retain];`

You now have an array which is retained. You have to release it later. If you don't, you will have a leak.

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb for memory management is simple:

For every `alloc`, `retain`, `copy`, or `new`, you must have a corresponding `release` or `autorelease`.

You are calling retain here:

```
fileList=[[fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:DOCUMENTS_FOLDER error:nil] retain];
```

but you don't release it.

Comment: if override this code like:fileList=[fileManager contentsOfDirecotryAtPath:DOCUMENT_FOLDER error:nil];it's leaks too!How?

Comment: @scofield: Same way. You must be retaining or copying it later and then failing to release that. Use Instruments's Leaks template—particularly the Object History feature—to see what you are leaking and how.